# Problems with length of successions in java

Tags: java

I am new to this, I hope you can help me. The teacher has left us homework, a program that calculates the following sequence: 3, 5, 5, 8, 7, 11, 9, 14, 11, 17.
To be able to generate it, use 2 distinct sequences and then combine them. But, the problem is that the length of happiness, is defined by entering a number by keyboard, and if that number is even, the sequence comes out with the number of correct terms, but if it is odd, I add an extra, this due to which it adds an independent counter to be able to determine the number of terms that the user specifies by keyboard for the succession
How can I make it work for both even and odd numbers?

Attachment code and capture:

```
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1= 3, n2= 5, rep, count=1;
    System.out.println("enter length");
    rep= sc.nextInt();
    for(int i= 1; i <= rep; i++)
    {
        if(count<= rep)
        System.out.print(n1+ ", " + n2 + ", ");
        n1= n1+2;
        count = count +1;
        n2= n2+3;
        count = count +1;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: So if I enter a length of 6, the output should be 6 numbers: `3, 5, 5, 8, 7, 11`.  But if I enter 5, the output should be just 5 numbers: `3, 5, 5, 8, 7`?

Comment: And by "add an extra," did you mean "add an extra number"?  Or "add an extra comma"?

Comment: Add a extra number, for example, i want 3 number of this sequence, but when i put the limit in 3, the anwers is 3,5,5,8

Comment: If i put in length 5, the result is: 3, 5, 5, 8, 7, 11. six terms, not 5

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking this, just print the `,` unless you are at the last iteration

```
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1= 3, n2= 5;
    System.out.println("enter length");
    int rep= sc.nextInt();
    for(int i= 0; i < rep; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(n1+ ", " + n2);
        if (i < rep -1) {
             System.out.print(", ");
        }
        n1= n1+2;
        n2= n2+3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `rep` is the number of terms you want to see in the combined sequence. If so then this should work:

```
for(int i=0; i < rep; i++)
{
    if((i % 2) ==0)
    {
      System.out.print(n1);
      n1 = n1+2;
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.print(n2);
      n2 = n2+3;
    }
    if(i+1 < rep) System.out.print(", ");
}
```

For rep == 6

```
3, 5, 5, 8, 7, 11
```

For rep == 7

```
3, 5, 5, 8, 7, 11, 9
```

If you want to get fancy you can use an array to store the sequences:

```
int[] n = {3, 5};
for(int i=0; i < rep; i++)
{
  System.out.print(n[i % 2]);
  if(i+1 < rep) System.out.print(", ");
  n[i % 2] += 2 + i % 2;
}
```